# How to read CSV file in Python spark - Error

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

Can you help me what is the error in this code, the file does exist but I know you are looking for it in HDFS sc.textFile("/user/spark/archivo.csv")

Or why does this error occur?

execution

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3
spark-submit --queue=OID Proceso_Match1.py
```

Python

```
import os
import sys

from pyspark.sql import HiveContext, Row
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

if __name__ =='__main__':
    conf=SparkConf().setAppName("Spark RDD").set("spark.speculation","true")
    sc=SparkContext(conf=conf)
    sc.setLogLevel("OFF")
    sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

    #rddCentral = sc.textFile("hdfs:///user/spark/archivo.csv")
    rddCentral = sc.textFile("/user/spark/archivo.csv")

    rddCentralMap = rddCentral.map(lambda line : line.split(","))

    print('paso 1')
    dfCentral = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rddCentralMap, ["ROWID_CDR","DURACION","FECHA_LLAMADA","FECHA_LLAMADA_2","MATCH"])
    dfCentral=dfCentral.withColumn("FECHA_LLAMADA_NUM",dfCentral.FECHA_LLAMADA_2.cast(IntegerType()))
    dfCentral=dfCentral.withColumn("DURACION_NUM",dfCentral.DURACION.cast(IntegerType()))
    dfCentral=dfCentral.withColumn("MATCH_NUM",dfCentral.MATCH.cast(IntegerType()))

    sc.stop()
```

Error log

```
22/09/30 12:49:14 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.8
paso 1
/usr/local/bin/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py:124: UserWarning: Could not import the lzma module. Your installed Python is incomplete. Attempting to use lzma compression will result in a RuntimeError.
  warnings.warn(msg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aic_proceso_vfs/rjaimea/vfs_504/bin/Proceso_Match1.py", line 21, in <module>
    dfCentral = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rddCentralMap, ["ROWID_CDR","DURACION","FECHA_LLAMADA","FECHA_LLAMADA_2","MATCH"])
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, cl-hdp-cdp-dn7.cse-cph.int, executor 1): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        ... 16 more
```

File HDFS

```
hdfs dfs -ls /user/spark

Found 3 items
drwxr-xr-x   - spark       hdfs           0 2022-07-25 10:11 /user/spark/.sparkStaging
-rw-------   3 hadoopadmin hdfs          21 2022-09-30 12:25 /user/spark/archivo.csv
drwxrwxrwt   - spark       spark          0 2022-09-30 12:33 /user/spark/driverLogs
```

[image]

Comment: Your error says `python3` executable doesn't exist on the Spark/YARN server, not that your file doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but it seems like you're mis-using the schema for the database being created

the line
`dfCentral = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rddCentralMap, ["ROWID_CDR","DURACION","FECHA_LLAMADA","FECHA_LLAMADA_2","MATCH"])`

takes the dict-like object that represents your dataframes data as the first parameter, and the schema for the second. You've just given a list of strings as the second argument.

In order to create the dataframe with some schema, you have to structure the fields that are in that list, then structure the list

so your program would look like this

```
import os
import sys

from pyspark.sql import HiveContext, Row
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import * #where structType and structField come from

if __name__ =='__main__':
    conf=SparkConf().setAppName("Spark RDD").set("spark.speculation","true")
    sc=SparkContext(conf=conf)
    sc.setLogLevel("OFF")
    sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

    #rddCentral = sc.textFile("hdfs:///user/spark/archivo.csv")
    rddCentral = sc.textFile("/user/spark/archivo.csv")

    rddCentralMap = rddCentral.map(lambda line : line.split(","))

    print('paso 1')

    dfFields = ["ROWID_CDR","DURACION","FECHA_LLAMADA","FECHA_LLAMADA_2","MATCH"]
    dfSchema = StructType([StructField(field_name, StringType(), True) for field_name in dfFields])
    dfCentral = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rddCentralMap, dfSchema)
    dfCentral=dfCentral.withColumn("FECHA_LLAMADA_NUM",dfCentral.FECHA_LLAMADA_2.cast(IntegerType()))
    dfCentral=dfCentral.withColumn("DURACION_NUM",dfCentral.DURACION.cast(IntegerType()))
    dfCentral=dfCentral.withColumn("MATCH_NUM",dfCentral.MATCH.cast(IntegerType()))

    sc.stop()
```

Alternatively, the [createDataFrame function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame) takes an [RDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/api/core/spark/RDD.html) as the first parameter. mapping the RDD created from reading the file may also be contributing to your issue

Comment: This isn't related to the error in the question. Also, you can use `spark.read.format("csv").load("file.csv")` rather than use RDDs